# Very new to PHP, why won't this if/elseif statemen work?

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP and I am trying to get this to work

```
<?php
$name =  $_GET['username'];
$pass =  $_GET['password'];
$authcheck = shell_exec("python authcheck.py  $name $pass");
if ( $authcheck == "Correct") {
  exec("python create.py names $name $pass");
} elseif ( $authcheck != "Correct"){
  echo "Incorrect username and password";
  exit;
}
?>
```

This always echos the `elseif` part. I thought maybe it was because `$authcheck` wasn't a string, so I did `$outcome = (string)$authcheck` and changed the rest of it to use `$outcome` instead of `$authcheck` but it didn't work.

The outcome of the Python script is exactly `Correct`

Comment: Did you check whats your response for `$authcheck`?

Comment: what does `var_dump`'ing reveal? and anything from http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ?

Comment: Vural, $authcheck (when I echo it) echos 'Correct'

Comment: Sorry Fred, I am not sure what that is, I am very new

Comment: Ok Fred, it dumps this `C:\wamp64\www\authorize\step2.php:6:string 'Correct
' (length=8)`

Comment: I bet, you have hidden characters in your string

Comment: you have a string, which is "Correct\0" and not 'Correct'

Comment: example: `var_dump($name);` or `var_dump($_GET);` along with examples of error reporting in http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php to catch and display, if there are errors.

Comment: so there's a trailing space in there, use `trim()` then. and remember that `Correct` and `correct` are two different animals, should that be the case.

Comment: Not sure of the answer (but a trailing space sound right) - but a suggestion - if there are only two options (Correct or Incorrect) you do not need the elseif. You simply need an else. Ie: if $authcheck is correct do this ELSE do that.

Comment: There is no need to make an `elseif` which checks for the opposite of the initial `if` - use plain `else` instead.

Comment: my guess is how the GET is being used and there's a space in there. again; make sure that `Correct` is the right letter case also.

Comment: Fred I don't think that is it, in the Python script, I use `print('Correct')` and it works fine out of the PHP

Comment: @WillB well someone upvoted that answer below... so ask them. I'll have to go now.

Comment: Try `$authcheck = trim(shell_exec("python authcheck.py  $name $pass"));`

Comment: Charlotte that worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: oh wait @CharlotteDunois  [I said that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935159/very-new-to-php-why-wont-this-if-elseif-statemen-work#comment67152279_39935159) but nobody listened to me about `trim()`. lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Poor Fred, want a cookie to cheer you up?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Only if it's during a long "session" lol

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Just go ahead and post your comment as an answer. Maybe a bit of plug for *moi* would be nice *lol* am kidding. Let's just close this question, I'm getting a bit tired looking at the other answers who haven't "nailed it" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your var_dump you have a space in your string: "Correct ".
But you compare to "Correct" without space.  Do you get it? ;-)

Comment: that's already been stated in comments, by "moi" ;-) so... the "solution" is what here exactly? oh yeah, `trim()`.

Comment: I tried changing it to `if ( $authcheck == "Correct ") {` but that doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Oh, then I wss to slow.  Good for you.  Keep going!  ;)

Comment: well the guy didn't bother telling me anything about my probable solution, so hey... more power to ya ;-)

Comment: @WillB so what does `echo $authcheck;` print?

Comment: It prints `Correct`

Comment: @WillB so no spaces and stuff? Are you shure?

Comment: @IgorUnger yes maybe seeing also the python script might help

Answer (score -4):

Try to print `$authcheck` before make the if.

You can print it in three different way:

- `echo $authcheck` This will print the value of **$authcheck**
- `print_r($authcheck)` This will print it with a formated output if **$authcheck** is an object or array otherwise will print the same think of echo.
- `var_dump($authcheck)` This will print the type and the value of **$authcheck**. In this way you can now if **$authcheck** is a string or a in or NULL

You can do the same thing with **$name** and **$pass**

Here you can found more information:

- shell_exec() http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php
- echo http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php
- print_r() http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php
- var_dump() http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: for crying outloud, `trim()` was the solution by moi...... and Charlotte.